# Complex MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following route in my MVC applicaiton:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{server}/{port}/{route}",
            defaults: new { 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                server = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                port = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                route = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This route gets hit when the URL is `http://localhost:80/api/myserver.mydomain.net/8080/mypage` but when I change the URL to `http://localhost:80/api/myserver.mydomain.svc/8080/mypage` the route suddenly does not get hit.  Any idea why simply changing an argument in my route from '.net' to '.svc' would stop working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/09/07/routing-and-build-providers.aspx/).  All I had to do was remove the .svc build provider from my site:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".svc"/>            
      </buildProviders>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.svc` is a path extension for WCF end points, so IIS will be processing this via a different mechanism (ISAPI module/handler) not through the MVC/WebAPI route engine.

Try adding the following to your `web.config`, it will force IIS to run the routing engine with each request.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
    .....
```

Note: this may add an unnecessary overhead to your page requests.

Another option might be to remove the module itself, but this will affect any WCF endpoints you may be running.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules> 
            <remove name="ServiceModel-4.0" />
    .....
```

Comment: I think you might be on to something with the ISAPI filters, unfortunately none of the suggestions above solved the problem.